# Brand new CPQ: how to get Price Action > Target Field populated? Only manually?

Tags: cpq, pricerule

Just have installed the CPQ Managed Package v220.10 on a blank Developer Org.

Now on an existing Org I found the Picklist for Target Field populated like this:

[image]

But on my brand new org it's only very sparsely populated:

[image]

**Question:**

Do I really have to populate all further fields **manually** or I there a setup which can help me to have a relevant fields showing up in that picklist without a manual copy&paste session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to enter the field names that you want to target in the picklist definition in setup. You could potentially build something using the metadata API, but that would be pretty difficult.

Answer (score 1):

I added the value I needed to Target Field but I can't see it when I try to build my Price Action. What's missing?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/173030)

Answer (score 0):

Just enter the target field picklist values according to your need. No need to have all of the values on one go.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

When you add the picklist value, make sure to include it as well in the Field Dependencies for Target Object.

Here's an example with SBQQ__ListPrice__c for Quote Line:

[image: Adding SBQQ__ListPrice__c in the Target Field]